# Getting no data found with SQL in JSP, while and if loop

Tags: sql, database, jsp, aggregate

I've been fighting with this for hours, and as far as I'm nearly there, I'm still completely off. This page links through a query to load a particular record of information for a picture selected on the previous page.

If I go to a link where the picture has no rating, it will load the page no problem with a rating of 0. If I click a page where I know it has a rating, it gives me a 'no data found' exception.

```
if (session.getAttribute("loginOK") != "true") {
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}

String id = request.getParameter("photoid");
Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:GalleryDB", "", "");
Statement st = cn.createStatement();
ResultSet r = st.executeQuery("SELECT AVG(rating) AS aRating, FileName, Title, Date, Location, Description FROM Photo LEFT JOIN Rating ON Photo.PhotoID = Rating.PhotoID WHERE Photo.PhotoID = " + id + " GROUP BY Rating.PhotoID, FileName, Title, Date, Location, Description;");

String html = "";
String image = "";

while (r.next()) {
    image += "<img align='right' src='images/" + r.getString("FileName") + "'/>";
    html += "Title: " + (r.getString("Title") + "</br></br>");
    html += "Date: " + (r.getString("Date") + "</br></br>");
    html += "Location: " + (r.getString("Location") + "</br></br>");
    html += "Description: " + (r.getString("Description") + "</br></br>");

    if (r.getString("aRating") != null) {
        html += "Rating: " + (r.getString("aRating"));
    } else {
        html += "0";
    }

}
cn.close();
```

Can anyone give any advice on why this is happening?

Comment: Did you check whether you have records when you execute your query in sqlplus or in backend?

Comment: Yes, the particular page giving the error deffinalty should come back with a rating average of 3. I've ran the same query in access with SQL (As seen as that's what we've been set *Sigh*) and I deffainly get a result then.

Comment: Seems like `id` isn't getting populated with the value you expect.  Have you tried printing out the SQL string rather than executing it, to ensure that `id` is getting the correct value?

Comment: Offtopic - Bad design; debugging should help.